# Python port scanner with multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
import threading, socket, sys, time
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()

if len(sys.argv) !=2 :
    print ("Usage: portscan.py <host>")
    sys.exit(1)

host = sys.argv[1]

def scan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        con = s.connect((host, port))
        with print_lock:
            print('Port: ' + str(port) + ' is open')
        con.close()
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while true:
        worker = q.qet()
        scan(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start

for worker in range(1, 1024):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

When I run it, it just hangs, I don't get any result and it doesn't give me any errors. I don't why it isn't working. It does working when I don't add the threading abilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were three minor mistakes:

1. while True
2. t.start()
3. q.get()

This corrected code seems to work for me:

```
import threading, socket, sys, time
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()

if len(sys.argv) !=2 :
    print ("Usage: portscan.py <host>")
    sys.exit(1)

host = sys.argv[1]

def scan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        con = s.connect((host, port))
        with print_lock:
            print('Port: ' + str(port) + ' is open')
        con.close()
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        scan(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for worker in range(1, 1024):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start() # <--- you have to call start? or is this a typo
```

Comment: Yeah, I need to call t.start() , I guess i forgot the () lol. Also I have q.qet instead of q.get (another typo lol) My code now works. Thanks :)